# Compound SQL SELECT

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables:

auth_user

- id
- username
- is_active (boolean)
  ...

useprofile_userprofile

- id
- user_id
  ...

How would I find all `auth_user` objects where `is_active`=0 and there is no userprofile_userprofile object with that `user_id`? For example, an entry like this --

auth_user

- id = 1
- username = hello@gmail.com
- is_active = 0

and `userprofile_userprofile` has no object where `user_id` = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    auth_user
WHERE
    auth_user.is_active=0
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                NULL
            FROM
                userprofile_userprofile 
            WHERE
                userprofile_userprofile.user_id=auth_user.id
        )
```

Comment: Thanks mate. You can have want ever there. `SELECT 1` or `SELECT 'somevalue'`.. But linq-to-sql uses `SELECT NULL`.. :P

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM auth_user A
LEFT JOIN userprofile_userprofile B ON A.id=B.user_id
WHERE A.is_active = false and B.user_id IS NULL
```

when `B.user_id` is `NULL` that means it cannot find a row where `user_id=1`.
This assumes that the id in table `userprofile_userprofile` are all not `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from auth_user au
where au.is_active = 0 and 
    not exists(select * from userprofile_userprofile uu where uu.user_id = au.user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other solutions you can also do it via `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
*
FROM
auth_user au
LEFT JOIN useprofile_userprofile uu ON au.id = uu.user_id
WHERE uu.id IS NULL
AND au.is_active = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Table Joins.  Reference this tutorial:

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

To answer your question, you are looking for something along the lines of:

"SELECT auth_user.username,auth_user.is_active,useprofile_userprofile.user_id WHERE is_active = 0 AND user_id != 1"

Answer (score 0):

```
select au.id,au.username,count(up.id) from auth_user au
left outer join useprofile_userprofile up
on au.id=up.user_id
where is_active = 1 
group by au.id,au.username
having count(up.id)=0
```